# How to reflect inheritance of classes in WPF/XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatemplate

(First: I have some programming experience but am a beginner with XAML/WPF/StackOverflow. So please forgive anything "stupid" and ask if anything is not clearly described or you need additional info. Thanks.)

Introduction:
I have a base class `Item` with some properties (like `Title`, `Notes`, etc.). 
From that I have some derived classes like `ContactItem`, `MediaItem`, etc. with additional properties which act as base classes for further specialized item types (e.g. `ImageItem`, `MusicItem` and `VideoItem` which are derived from `MediaItem`; `Person` and `Institution` are derived from `ContactItem`).

In WPF I want a page where multiple item types can be displayed together. I currently use an `ItemsPanel` for this and started to specify data templates for each item type - and there are many (more than 50).

Problem:
What I now want is some kind of "inheritance" of the item controls (e.g. have a "base" `UserControl` with a `ContentPresenter` and add additional controls for additional properties of derived classes/control templates).

What would be the best way to handle this in WPF/XAML without having to copy/paste the controls from the base classes for the derived item types in the data templates?

Any idea or hint in the right direction would be great. 
If you need some code or additional info, please let me know.

Comment: @Chris: Thank You for editing my question! I learned from it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You *could* simply nest each base class `UserControl` inside more derived `UserControl`s, but you could find that this might soon become unmanageable. Another way would be to use the `ContentControl` element to display sections of larger `DataTemplate`s from other `DataTemplate`s like this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="NameTemplate" DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:UserViewModel}">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
</DataTemplate>
...
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:UserDerivedViewModel}">
    <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" 
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource NameTemplate}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age}" />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Thank You Sheridan! Your sample helps a lot. But in my case I also  not only want to append property controls but also be able to "insert" them between the property controls of the base class's template. Is there a way to do this with your approach?

Comment: No. I wasted a lot of time searching for these types of things when I first got into WPF... it's so very different from other languages and new developers are always mistakenly searching for parts of WPF that they can relate with these other languages. WPF is generally a verbose language... you'll find lots of repeated code and code split up all over the place, but even if you could do what you wanted, you'd soon find that it's just so much easier defining one (or more) complete `DataTemplate` for each data type.

Comment: Thanks again for saving me a lot of time trying! I will accept your approach as an answer, because it may suit in a lot of cases for others.